# Can't specify dojox.mobile.TextBox type as password programmatically

Tags: mobile, input, textbox, passwords, dojo

I'm trying to build a login widget for our system, so I'm building the inputs programmatically. The Username input is easy, but I'm having issues with the input rendering with the correct type. When the page loads, the characters still show instead of hiding.

`var LoginPWInput = new dojox.mobile.TextBox({
     type: "password"
     , jsId: "loginPassword"
     , placeHolder: "Password"
     , style: "width:200px;float:right;"
     , onkeypress: "loginKeyPress(event);"
     , tabIndex: "2"
     }, document.createElement('input'));
LoginPW.addChild(LoginPWInput);`

I've also tried `LoginPWInput.set('type','password');` to not avail.

Any ideas on how to do this correctly? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another, better way to do it. Code is below:

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.innerHTML = "<input type='password' />";
var inp = dv.firstChild;
var LoginPWInput = new dojox.mobile.TextBox({
     id: "loginPasswordNew"
     , jsid: "loginPasswordNew"
     , placeHolder: "Password"
     , class: "loginRightSide nofix loginPasswordNew"
     , style: "width:200px;float:right;outline:none;"
     , tabIndex: "2"
}, inp);
```

Now it works.